# Windows equivalent to Mac Location

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

Is there any Windows equivalent to the Location functionality of Mac OS X?

I'm looking on a quick way to change the wireless setting based on different locations, such as Home, Work, etc.

A free option would be appreciated a bit more :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Avanquest Connection Manager](http://www.avanquest.com/USA/software/avanquest-connection-manager-107347) - it's free.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what version of Windows you're using, or exactly what it is about wireless settings that you're trying to change? Being a Windows user, not a Mac user I'm not sure what Location does.

I'm guessing that it is similar to the way that Windows 7 (and to a lesser extent Vista) classify different network types and change things like your media sharing options depending on whether you're on a public, home or office network? If so that's controlled by the Network Location Awareness service on Windows.

If you're on Vista, you can go into the Network and Sharing Centre and below where it shows your current internet connection, it will have a kine saying what type of network it thinks you're on, eg ***Network*** (Private Network) Beside this is a Customize link that you can use to change the network type. And below it lists all the Windows networking features it is enabling/disabling on your type of connection at the moment, eg File Sharing, Printer Sharing, Media Sharing. You

[This is an article on the improvements Windows 7 made to this feature over Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2008/12/30/at-home-with-homegroup-in-windows-7.aspx).

If you're talking about things like saving the WEP/WPA password and connection settings for each wireless network you connect to, then the built-in Windows wireless functionality already does that and saves it based on the connection's SSID, and has done since at least XP SP1.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used a Mac but from memory Location also lets you set different web proxies based on location, and for dialup (and ADSL) you can use different settings in different locations.

Comment: It's not quite this - it's a set of presets for different networks like proxy settings etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Net Profiles](http://code.google.com/p/netprofiles/).  It's a small (500 KB) open source application.  I haven't used it recently, but it used to do what you want.